# Для чего использовать директивы условной компиляции (#define #if #endif)?

Tags: c++, компиляция, g++, директива

Как их использовать? Лучше они или хуже? Хедеры записаны с их использованием, значит они удобны?

Answer (score 7):

Обычно единственным разумным применением директив препроцессора является обеспечение невозможности повторного включения include-файлов.

Предположим, ситуацию

**a.h**

```
#include <something.h>
...
```

**b.h**

```
#include <something.h>
...
```

**c.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h" // вопрос - сколько раз будет включен something.h?
...
```

Чтоб не было повторного включения заголовочны файлов и, соответственно, ошибки о повторном определении идентификаторов (переменных, функций, классов...), текст в h-файле обрамляют так:

**something.h**

```
#ifndef _SOMETHING_H_
#define _SOMETHING_H
...
#endif // _SOMETHING_H
```

Получается, что если заголовочный файл был однажды включен, то макрос `_SOMETHING_H` определен и второй раз заголовочный файл включен не будет.

Альтернативный способ сделать тоже самое - использование конструкции `#pragma once`

Еще директивы условной компиляции применяются для сборки из одного дерева исходных кодов нескольких целей. Это может быть удобно для:

1. Разграничения Release и Debug версий вашего приложения.
2. Обрамления архитектурно-зависимых кусков вашего приложения, например, при сборке под разные программные или аппаратные платформы.
3. При написании библиотек - для использовании одних и тех же h-файлов внутри самой библиотеки и для ее пользователей. Понятное дело, что определения в этих файлах должны немного, но отличаться.

В остальном - к макросам нужно относиться очень аккуратно, т.к. существуют другие, более безопасные языковые средства. Например, можно отметить перечисления (enum) и шаблоны (templates).

Answer (score 2):

Это стандартный инструмент языка, необходимый для осуществления условной компиляции. Обычно на C добавляют заголовки вида

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
    /* Код заголовка */
#endif
```

Чтобы они многократно не включались. А также в тех случаях, когда необходимо менять код в зависимости от чего бы то ни было: от процессора, платформы, и тд.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать #pragma once. Разница между ними в том, что pragma once не поддерживается стандартом, но MVS и gcc её поддерживают. Это должно снизить время компиляции больших проектов.

Answer (score 1):

В основном их используют для определения поведения на разных системах. Некоторые из них объявляет компилятор. Поэтому используя их тебе не придется писать обработчик типа- какая система у нас тоит и инклудить нужные файлы.